# MySQL Returning Value in Stored Proc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is a very easy stored proc but I can't get it to work.  I want to count up the number of records based upon some filters passed in.  The where clause works perfectly (it's used in another stored proc to return values).  In this Stored proc, I just want the TOTAL COUNT based on the "where".  I'm calling it like this:
call countthem('column1', 'AA', 'LIKE', @outfiltercount);
But, I'm getting the error message back "Error Code 1327: Undeclared variable: countit"

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE countthem(
  IN infilterfield  varchar(25),  
  IN infiltervalue varchar(100), 
  IN infiltertype varchar(10),
  OUT outfiltercount INT)


BEGIN

DECLARE SQLStatement varchar(255);
DECLARE countit INT;


SET @filterfield = infilterfield;
SET @filtervalue = infiltervalue; 
SET @filtertype = infiltertype;

SET outfiltercount = 0;

SET @filterstring = '';

IF infiltertype is not null and infiltertype != ''

  THEN

     IF infiltertype like 'EQUALS'
        THEN
           SET @filterstring = CONCAT(' WHERE ', @filterfield, ' ', ' = ', ' \'', @filtervalue, '\'');
     ELSE
           SET @filterstring = CONCAT(' WHERE ', @filterfield, ' ', ' LIKE ', ' \'%', @filtervalue, '%\'');
     END IF;
END IF;  

SET @SQLStatement = CONCAT('select count(*) into countit from vsltable ', @filterstring);

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLStatement;

EXECUTE stmt;   

set outfiltercount = countit;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your countit variable is never assigned.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it's never assigned?  I tried setting it to 0 right before it goes into the "IF".... but, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SET @SQLStatement = CONCAT('select count(*) into countit from vsltable ', @filterstring);
```

to

```
SET @SQLStatement = CONCAT('select count(*) as countit from vsltable ', @filterstring);
```

thus replacing `select ... into` by `select ... as`.